# Stop Web Page Page From Jumping To The Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I am trying to update my website with a sticky navigation bar like so:

```
<div id ="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-top"><!--Navigation Bar-->
        <li class="navbar-brand">TechU</li>
        <li><a href="index.aspx">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.aspx">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.aspx">Resume</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><!--Start Dropdown-->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"><!--Dropdown Menu-->
                <li><a href="#">Facebook <img src="Media/Images/Icons/FaceBook.ico" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Twitter <img src="Media/Images/Icons/Twitter(1).ico" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WordPress <img src="Media/Images/Icons/Wordpress.ico" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Android Apps <img src="Media/Images/Icons/android.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">YouTube <img src="Media/Images/Icons/Youtube.ico" /></a></li>
            </ul><!--End Dropdown Menu-->
        </li>
    </ul><!--End Navigation Bar-->
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript that I am using:

```
    var mn = $(".nav"),
    hdr = $('#hero').height();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scrollPos >= hdr) {
            mn.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            mn.removeClass('nav-top');
        } else {
            mn.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            mn.addClass('nav-top');
        }
    });
```

The problem I am having is that if a page isn't long enough to scroll but the top of the page hits the top of the navbar then the page will jump straight back to the top. My website is TechUHost.com so you can go and look at it for yourself as well.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using the bootstrap class and instead create your own as you can make it look more fluid. Something like this with a css class.

```
<div id="navSpy"></div>
    <div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button id="nav-button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar icon-bar-up"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar icon-bar-middle"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar icon-bar-down"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Deft</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li ><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


$(function () {
    var e = $("#navSpy").offset().top;
    var t = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        e = $("#navSpy").offset().top + 15;
        t = $(window).scrollTop()
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        t = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (e < t) {
            $("#nav").addClass("navbar-sticky");
        } else {
            $("#nav").removeClass("navbar-sticky");
        }
    })
});

//CSS
.navbar-sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't actually have a bootstrap `navbar`. According to bootstrap docs,

`Be sure to use a <nav> element or, if using a more generic element such as a <div>, add a role="navigation" to every navbar to explicitly identify it as a landmark region for users of assistive technologies.`

There are several ways to implement a sticky navbar. Assuming that you do not need responsiveness, I hope the following code helps you.

```
<body>
  <div id="hero">
    ...
  </div>
  <nav id ="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TechU</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Social Media
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Android</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  ...
  ...
</body>
```

And the corresponding javascript is,

```
  var navbar = $("#navbar");
  var heroHeight = $('#hero').height();
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrolled >= heroHeight)
      navbar.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    else
      navbar.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
  });
```